# how to keep alpha and beta apps on an android device

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to keep two versions of an app on my device: the working and the beta.
The apps install over each other. Is there a way to do this?  I've tried copying the directory to a new directory and using refactor to change the directory structure and changing package names and and the label in the Manifest and nothing so far has worked.  What do I have to do to change the app apk install path?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep *both* debug and store version of your app by modifying your `build.gradle`.

Add into your `buildTypes`

```
debug {
    applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
}
```

This will modify package name by adding `.debug` to it automatically with every debug build.

Comment: To expand on this, you can create multiple flavors as well so you can keep multiple release builds, using .alpha and .beta. This flow works really well with CI/CD tools, so you can automate the whole process straight from source control.

Answer (score 0):

I use Product Flavours to have different versions of app on device.
Here is a sample -

```
productFlavors {

    production {
        applicationId "com.app.production"
        versionName "1.x.x"
    }

    staging {
        applicationId "com.app.staging"
        versionName "1.x.x staging"
    }

}
```

You can even create additional RES or SRC directories for each flavour. For more info on this, check [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants) link on developer site. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks poss, @Sree. Either of these should work and the link above looks like exactly what I need to know.  More learning curve... :)